# Performance problem when using Google maps

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

The problem is that I am using Google Maps with markers in Firebase, and when opening a marker (in @override) I need to have Google Maps open in the background.

By having Google Maps open in the background, the app runs a little slow when I have a marker open on my Pixel 2 (virtual machine) or on a Huawei mate 10 lite that I use as a low-end device to test my Android apps.

I have tried several alternatives to try to "hide" Google Maps, but when I enter the marker it gives me a null value.

Some alternatives have been "Visibility(" and "Offstage(". But it got null.

And my last alternative has been to create a card, with the photo, title and description of the bookmark in Firebase and clicking on the card opens a separate full screen page. What is the problem? that the functions were not updated. There are various functions like liking, commenting, etc.

These functions only worked when I go back and reopen the bookmark the changes were made.

I also have to say that not because there was more information, the application was slower, since one day I deleted practically all the code (photo, description, comments, bookmark date...) except the title, and it worked slow just the same.

We could say that my bookmark code starts here;

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          if (isMarkerInfoVisible && selectedMarkerData != null)
            GoogleMap(
              liteModeEnabled: true,
              rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
              scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
              tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
              myLocationEnabled: false,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              compassEnabled: false,
              mapToolbarEnabled: false,
              initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition(),
              mapType: MapType.satellite,
            )
          else
            GoogleMap(
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              mapToolbarEnabled: false,
              initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition(),
              mapType: MapType.hybrid,
              onMapCreated: (controller) {
                mapController = controller;
              },
              markers: _markers,
            ),
          if (isMarkerInfoVisible && selectedMarkerData != null)
            WillPopScope(
```

In short... if the marker is open, a "MapType.satellite" map is displayed, without further information.

If it is not open, the other map (MapType.hybrid) is displayed and shows some more information, including markers.

I have to say that if the background of the Container is black and alpha 0.8 for example. You can see the map in the background and it gives a very good feeling.

But having the map open consumes a lot of resources for me.

The only way I navigated smoothly was by taking the marker to a separate page, not in the Override;

```
void _openPopupWindow(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        fullscreenDialog: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('aaa'),
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ),
            body: Container(
```

Everything works VERY FLUID but as I said before it gives me a lot of errors... the easiest and fastest option would be to solve the problem and make all the marker code stay in the Override without having to take it somewhere else.

I have also tried;

```
liteModeEnabled: true,
mapType: MapType.none,
```

And I have not been able to navigate the scoreboard on my Huawei mate 10 lite fluently.

Sorry for my English, any help or suggestion is good. Thanks in advance.